# Removing the maxlength attribute

Tags: javascript, html, maxlength

is it possible to remove a maxlength attribute from an element?
I thought that setting it to 0 would work, but it seems like FF4 then prevents entering anything. http://jsfiddle.net/hMc4y/

I've heard that setting it to `-1` does trigger an error and `removeAttribute` does not work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using "removeAttribute('maxLength')" should work fine; perhaps the surprise is that the attribute name must be "`maxLength`" with an uppercase "L".  Consider:

```
<form name="f">
  <input name="t" type="text" maxlength="5"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var t = document.f.t;
  alert(t.maxLength); // 5
  t.removeAttribute('maxLength');
  alert(t.maxLength); // 524288 (on Chrome/10.0.648.134)
</script>
```

Comment: Possibly it really was the lowercase issue. Thanks

Comment: Setting it to `undefined` does not work, btw. In recent versions of IE and FF that would set the maxLength to zero, making any input impossible

Comment: `removeAttribute('maxLength')` is the only way that will work here. Any modern browser will set `maxLength` to 0 when setting it to undefined.

Answer (score 2):

removeAttribute works for me in both Firefox 3.5 and Chrome.